# Looking for a better alternative to PIL for basic image file I/O and processing in Python?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Are there better alternatives to PIL ([Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)) for basic image file I/O and processing in Python?

Comment: @Jarret Hardie: you beat me to it!

Comment: Better : faster, more functionality, active development, etc.

Comment: Since this question is closed I can't actually post an answer. You might want to look into the [aggdraw](http://www.effbot.org/zone/aggdraw-index.htm) module which provides antialiasing and better functionality on top of PIL/Pillow. Alternatively, take a look at the [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/) bindings for Python: [PyCairo](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/)

Answer (score 8):

Try Pillow: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow

It's a fork of PIL but maintained by Plone community. Which is great as it is being maintained (in comparison to it's predecessor) and it is backward compatible with PIL. Existing code will work out of the box with Pillow.

They mostly focus on packaging issues and AFAIK this was the biggest pain with PIL.

Good luck!

Comment: Pillow is pretty great, as it supports both PyPy and Python. But using Pillow with PyPy is not very optimal as it's written in CPYthons C-Api, and therefor slower on PyPy.

Comment: `pillow` looks much better than `pil`

Comment: Pillow has no antialiasing support which can make for crummy images. You might want to take a look at the (outdated?) [aggdraw](http://www.effbot.org/zone/aggdraw-index.htm) module.

Comment: Pillow currently has antialiasing support (I thought they did since the beginning, but now it's enabled by default). If you're making a thumbnail (for example) and want to be explicit: `my_image.thumbnail((128, 128), Image.BICUBIC)`

Answer (score 6):

If by 'better' you mean "faster" or "less memory intensive" or (the big one in my experiments) "able to handle much larger images," you might be able to use the Python interface to VIPS:

http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/index.php?title=Python

However, if 'better' means "well-tested in Python," or "Windows-friendly," VIPS won't fit the bill.

Comment: VIPS has a new Python binding since April 2015. It's now nicely Pythonic, works on Windows, does not leak, and is complete. The VIPS test suite is now in Python, so it should all work. Typically 5x faster than Pillow. http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/supported/current/doc/html/libvips/using-from-python.html

Answer (score 5):

Not really. PIL is pretty much what everybody uses. I've never had any difficulties with it myself. *However*, if you really don't like it, you could check out PythonMagick or PythonMagickWand, which are wrappers around ImageMagick, which may be more to your taste.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest [Python Wand](http://dahlia.kr/wand/), which is a ctypes-based simple [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) binding for Python.

Comment: Downside is that Wand is not very speedy in CPython. EG: Pixel-access is useless. Upside: PyPy compatible.

Answer (score 3):

[Wand](http://dahlia.kr/wand/) is a great library for simple manipulation like image file format conversion, cropping, resizing, watermarking and basic compositing.  It's build on top of ImageMagick's MagicWand C library, but exposes a beautiful Pythonic API.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your task, but [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) has [Python bindings](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/index.html), you could read the docs and see if  it is suited to what you have to do.

Comment: OpenCV is rather for computer vision and 3D processing.

Comment: You can use PILasOPENCV which you find at https://github.com/bunkahle/PILasOPENCV - it is a wrapper around common PIL functions but uses OpenCV internally